# Using set_array with pyplot.pcolormesh ruins figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a xx and yy matrix created with `np.meshgrid` and a `grid` matrix of values created by operating on xx and yy. Then I plot the results using `graph = plt.pcolormesh(...` and get this:

[image]

Then when I try to update the `grid` matrix in the plot using `graph.set_array(grid.ravel())` it causes the figure to be thwarted.

[image]

Does anyone know how to avoid this?

Here is my full code if it helps:

```
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from obspy import read

dx = 5   # km
dt = 5   # sec
nx = 500
ny = 500

v = 3.5  # km/s
p = 1/v

t_min = np.int_(np.sqrt((nx*dx)**2 + (ny*dx)**2))/v
nt = np.int_(t_min/dt)

# Receiver position
rx = 40 * dx
ry = 40 * dx

# Signal with ones
signal = np.zeros(2*nt)
signal[0:len(signal):len(signal)/10] = 1

# Create grid:
x_vector = np.arange(0, nx)*dx
y_vector = np.arange(0, ny)*dx
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x_vector, y_vector)

# Distance from source to grid point
rr = np.int_(np.sqrt((xx - rx)**2 + (yy - ry)**2))

# travel time grid
tt_int = np.int_(rr/v)
tt = rr/v

# Read window of signal
wlen = np.int_(t_min/dt)
signal_window = signal[0:wlen]
grid = signal_window[tt_int/dt]

ax = plt.subplot(111)
graph = plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, grid, cmap=mpl.cm.Reds)
plt.colorbar()
plt.plot(rx, ry, 'rv', markersize=10)
plt.xlabel('km')
plt.ylabel('km')
# plt.savefig('anitestnormal.png', bbox_inches='tight')

signal_window = signal[wlen:wlen * 2]
grid = signal_window[tt_int/dt]
graph.set_array(grid.ravel())


# plt.ion()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm thinking that set_array updates grid to a matrix with different dimensions, maybe with one column less, causing the apparent diagonal in the second figure when filling it with grid.ravel(). But I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is rather tricky ... but I believe that your assertion about the dimensions is correct.  It has to do with how pcolormesh creates the QuadMesh object.

The documentation states that:

> A quadrilateral mesh is represented by a (2 x ((meshWidth + 1) * (meshHeight + 1))) numpy array coordinates

In this context, meshWidth is your `xx`, meshHeight is your `yy`.  When you set the array explicitly using set_array, pcolormesh wants to interpret it directly as the (meshWidth x meshHeight) quadrilaterals, and therefore requires one less point in each dimension.

When I tested it, I got the following behavior - if you change

```
graph.set_array(grid.ravel())
```

to

```
graph.set_array(grid[:-1,:-1].ravel())
```

your plot will look like it should.

In the code, it looks like in the initial call to pcolormesh, if `xx` and `yy` are given, they should actually be defined to have one more point in each dimension than the value array, and if they don't (are off by 1), then the array is truncated by one value *automatically*.  So, you should get the same answer even if you use `grid[:-1,:-1]` in the first call as well.

Comment: See also [this answere](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31490420/859591) and [this bug report](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/107).

Comment: This has been driving me mad all evening but this fixed it.